# What does [class^=blah] means in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

What does this CSS selector means;

[class^=blah]

Regards.

Comment: Can someone also tell me why my question is downvoted?

Comment: Because if you'd google for a bit, instead of asking it here, you'd find the answer easily. -1 is for lack of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the CSS **attribute starts with** selector. `[class^="blah"]` literally means:

> An element with an attribute of `class` which starts with `blah`.
>   For example: `blahello` or `blahfoobar`

See **[the Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)**

Answer (score -2):

As written here: [CSS3 [attribute^=value] Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)

This selector matches every element whose specified attribute is a specific value.

For example:

I have the following html

```
<a href="www.google.com">Lorem Ipsum</a>
<a href="myhomepage.com">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
```

and I want to color all the links to my homepage in a different color, I would do

```
a[href="myhomepage.com"]
{
   color: #00FF00;
}
```

This selects all a elements whose href attribute equals myhomepage.com.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4F6w/2/) here

Comment: The only reason I'm -1ing this post is because of the W3schools reference. . w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: 1/ Whose specified attribute *begins* with a specific value. 2/ http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Even the example given here is incorrect... you're using a different attribute selector.